# How to call two model functions in a controller? LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new on this world, and I am trying to learn some in PHP with LARAVEL.

And I'm trying to make a Search Input, and I have some problems.

How can I call two differents Model functions in a Controller?

In my Model I have this two functions:

```
public static function Peticion(){
    return DB::table('usados')
        ->join('marcas', 'marcas.id', '=', 'usados.marca_id')
        ->select('usados.*', 'marcas.nombre')
        ->paginate(9);
}

public function scopeSearch($query, $buscar){
    return $query->where('modelo', 'LIKE', "%$buscar%");
}
```

and in my Controller I have this:

```
public function usados(Request $request) { 
    Usados::Search($request->buscar); 
    $usado = Usados::Peticion();
    return view('usados', compact('usado'));
}
```

And this is my Search Button:

```
{!!Form::open(['method'=>'GET', 'class'=>'navbar-form', 'align'=>'center'])!!}
    <div class="form-group">
      {!!Form::text('buscar', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Buscar...'])!!}
      {!!Form::submit('Buscar',['class'=>'btn btn-buscador'])!!}
    </div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

'Peticion' Function it's work perfectly and list some articles, but the 'scopeSearch' Function isn't work, how can I make/call correctly this function?? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Laracast video will clear your how to use Eloquent Model :

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/11

Answer (score 0):

There is no secret around how to call multiple functions model.

You only need to [retrieve](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models) correctly the result of query and store it in a variable, for example.

```
$result = Usados::search('your search term here')->get();
dd($result); // See the function return.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your model

```
public static function Peticion(){
    return DB::table('usados')
    ->join('marcas', 'marcas.id', '=', 'usados.marca_id')
    ->select('usados.*', 'marcas.nombre')
    ->paginate(9);
}

public function scopeSearch($query,$buscar){
    return $query->where('modelo', 'LIKE', "%$buscar%");
}
```

> Your controller

```
public function usados(Request $request) { 
    $usado = Usados::Peticion()->search($request['buscar']);
    return view('usados', compact('usado'));
}
```

> Your View

```
{!!Form::open(['method'=>'GET', 'class'=>'navbar-form', 'align'=>'center'])!!}
<div class="form-group">
  {!!Form::text('buscar', $usado->name, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Buscar...'])!!}
  {!!Form::submit('Buscar',['class'=>'btn btn-buscador'])!!}
</div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: what this referred to? "$usado->name" in my view? because isn't work with or without this.. :( 
If I put 'null' show me this message => Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
If I put '$usado->name' show me this => Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: that mean your sql result set is empty.